# Ansible output only writing one device to the file

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm new to Ansible and trying to get ios_facts from 2 test devices. As you can see in the output, Ansible go through both devices but write only the 1st device to the destination file. I'm pretty sure much needed to get the output I'm looking for. Could someone please tell me what else needed or push me towards the right direction? Thank you very much in advance.

Host file

```
[LocationA]
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

jinja template:

```
{% for host in groups['LocationA'] %}
hostname: {{ ansible_net_hostname }}
version: {{ ansible_net_version }}
File_system: {{ ansible_net_filesystems_info }}
Neighbors: {{ansible_net_neighbors }} {{ansible_net_model}}
model: {{ansible_net_model}}
{% endfor %}
```

Playbook-

```
 - name: Gathering IOS facts
  hosts: LocationA
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Gather IOS device facts
    ios_facts:
      gather_subset: all

#  - name: View ansible fact keys
#    debug:
#      var: ansible_facts.keys()

  - name: output to a file
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: ./templates/md5-result.j2
      dest: ./devices/switch-facts.txt
      newline_sequence: '\r\n'
```

Output-

```
hostname: 1.1.1.1
version: 16.12.04
File_system: {'flash:': {'spacetotal_kb': 1583952.0, 'spacefree_kb': 557316.0}}
Neighbors: {} WS-C3850-48T
model: WS-C3850-48T
hostname: 1.1.1.1
version: 16.12.04
File_system: {'flash:': {'spacetotal_kb': 1583952.0, 'spacefree_kb': 557316.0}}
Neighbors: {} WS-C3850-48T
model: WS-C3850-48T
```

Comment: While looping through `locationA` hosts, you should reference the `hostvars[host]` Ansible facts to get the facts of the `host` item in the loop.